# What is the value of $ \lim _{x \to 0} \frac{\sin (3x) \sin (5x)}x ?$

Tags: calculus, limits

What is the value of$$ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin (3x)\sin(5x)}{x}$$

My answer is $1$, I multiplied by $x^2$ to get $\frac{\sin 3x}{x^2}$ so that they could = $\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $$\lim_{x\to 0} 3x\frac{\sin 3x}{3x}\ \  5\frac{\sin 5x}{5x}$$

Comment: Is the answer 15?

Comment: No, the answer is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Use

Sin A Sin B $= \frac{1}{2}\{ Cos(A-B) - Cos(A+B) \}$, we get

$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin3x \sin 5x}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{2x} \{\cos 2x -\cos 8x\}$

Use L' Hospital's Rule we get

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{2} \{\frac{\sin 2x}{2} -\frac{\sin 8x}{8}\} = 0$$